# Problems with firing two javascript functions on page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to launch two javascript functions when my page loads.

A function to initialize a Google map:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.015460,18.498087);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
            clickableIcons: false 
    };
    }
```

A function to autofocus on an input field when the map initializes and the page loads:

```
function inputfocus() {
    document.getElementById("pac-input").focus();
}
```

To launch the functions above I am using the following piece of code:

```
function start() {
    initialize();
    inputfocus();
}
window.onload = start;
```

The issue I am facing is that the functions work just fine separately but with the sequence as above only the first one fires (i.e. only the map loads).

I've read and tested a number of ideas available on stackoverflow and other websites but none of the worked.

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to fix this issue.

A demonstrative example would look like this (requires adding Google Maps own key):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
      #mapindex {
        height: 400px;  
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourapikeygoeshere&libraries=places&types=(cities)" ></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps API -->    

    <script>

        function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.015460,18.498087); // Map is centered here  
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
                clickableIcons: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapindex"), myOptions);


        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
          if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
          }
          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

           // Create a marker for each place.
            var image = 'http://www.instead.com.pl/target2.png';
              markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
              }));

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });


        }

    </script>

    <script>

        function inputFocus() {
            document.getElementById("pac-input").focus();
        }

    </script>

    <script>
        function start() {
          initialize();
          inputFocus();
        }
        window.onload = start;
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter location" value="<?php if(isset ($_GET['local'])){ echo $_GET['local'];}?>"/>
    <div id="mapindex"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try logging something in inputfocus method. That will clear that method is being called or not. If it is called then make sure there is an input field available in dom with id = "pac-input" before you try to focus it.

Comment: Try to set focus with some `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`, as sometimes it happens that some rendering involved and focus gets lost. E.q. `setTimeout(inputfocus, 1000)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add a delay on the setFocus (as suggested by Sergii Vorobei in the comments) it works.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
  setTimeout(inputFocus, 1000);
});
```

(you probably don't need the "idle" event listener, but it is probably safer)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/67fhpzxu/)

**code snippet:**

```css
#mapindex {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&types=(cities)"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Google Maps API -->

<script>
  function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.015460, 18.498087); // Map is centered here  
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
      clickableIcons: false
    };

    function inputFocus() {
      document.getElementById("pac-input").focus();
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapindex"), myOptions);


    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        var image = 'http://www.instead.com.pl/target2.png';
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
      // inputFocus();
      setTimeout(inputFocus, 1000);
    });

  }
</script>

<script>
  function start() {
    initialize();
  }
  window.onload = start;
</script>


<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter location" value="Nebraska" />

<div id="mapindex"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed. Thank you geocodezip and Sergii Vorobei for your help.